# Failed to download package

Tags: apt, updates, archive

I tried to install updates from the update manager but it always displays an error message `Failed to download package file` and the details is:

> Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/h/hplip/hplip-data_3.10.6-1ubuntu10.2_all.deb The HTTP server sent an invalid Content-Range header [IP: 91.189.92.167 80]

Please can someone help me out.

Thanks for your response...

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a package partially downloaded and is having trouble completing.  Open up a terminal and run

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

Then try the update again.